# properties that are lists, assigning to index

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

When using properties to get/set lists of attributes, it would appear that the same boilerplate code that works for single objects doesn't work for containers. (or, it does, and i'm doing it wrong.)

Example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             self.x = x
...             self.y = y
...     @property
...     def pos(self):
...             return [self.x, self.y]
...     @pos.setter
...     def pos(self, xy):
...             self.x, self.y = xy
... 
>>> Stick = A(10, 20)
>>> Stick.x
10
>>> Stick.y
20
>>> Stick.pos
[10, 20]
>>> Stick.pos = [5, 10]
>>> Stick.x
5
>>> Stick.y
10
>>> Stick.pos
[5, 10]
```

So far so good; however, when trying to assign to `Stick.pos[0]`, I run into trouble.

```
>>> Stick.pos[0] = 70
>>> Stick.x
5
>>> Stick.pos
[5, 10]
```

Now, of course, one *could* simply never do this and just assign directly to `obj.x`, but it does prompt me to wonder how this should be done if one were to assume that only the `obj.pos` attribute allowed for assignment. *Is* there a way to successfully assign to `obj.pos[i]` when `pos` is a property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because when you call `Stick.pos[0]`, you're calling the getter for `pos`, which returns a list object with two integers equal to `self.x` and `self.y`, but not actual references to `self.x` and `self.y`. That state of that list isn't maintained internally in your class, so the changes you make to it are lost.

However, you can get this behavior by storing `x` and `y` in a `list` internally, and using `property` to get/set them:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.xy = [x, y]

    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.xy

    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, xy):
        self.xy = xy

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.xy[0]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x): 
        self.xy[0] = x 

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.xy[1]

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y): 
        self.xy[1] = y
```

Output:

```
>>> Stick = A(10, 20)
>>> Stick.x
10
>>> Stick.y
20
>>> Stick.pos
[10, 20]
>>> Stick.pos = [5,10]
>>> Stick.x
5
>>> Stick.y
10
>>> Stick.pos
[5, 10]
>>> Stick.pos[0] = 70
>>> Stick.x
70
>>> Stick.pos
[70, 10]
```

Comment: Ahhh, the reverse angle approach :) yeah, I understood that `obj.pos` was calling a getter, I suppose I'd just hoped that there was some magic with the `@property` decorator that would have taken care of index assignment. Meh, this is probably just as good for my purposes.

Comment: Although I suppose at that point, the real answer is that `obj.pos` should probably not be a `@property`, just an attribute, and let `obj.x` and `obj.y` be the properties. So `obj.xy` may just as well be `obj.pos = [x, y]`, and then it can just be worked with directly, yeah?

Comment: @Stick Yeah, If you're not doing anything with the `pos` property other than returning `self.xy`, there's really no need for it to be a property at all.